# Allow users to customize strings that are later interpreted with embedded expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, mongodb, string-interpolation

Originally we built out a service on Rails that used static strings with embedded expressions (#{}) for values like the datetime of an object. These strings were used to build communications to other users.

We want to provide a way for our users to customize default text with embedded expressions.

They are currently scattered throughout our models, controllers and views, but we want to put them all in one place (like localization, but it is different per user).

Our initial thinking is to use MongoDB (via MongoMapper) to create a customization document that stores the strings. Then we can continuously add new strings without doing a migration.

We would store the string as something like this:

```
"Testing out a string at #{object.datetime}."
```

Later a user can use a form we have to edit these strings for their use (isolated from other users).

Then when we want to use the string we would either replace the #{} with a value or somehow tell the embedded expression evaluate then.

**Question:** how do I later calculate a string with embedded expressions after it is defined? Is there something like to_sym for creating symbols?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How complex would embedded expressions be? Is it Ruby? A subset? How values you want to interpolate will be passed?

Comment: Generally, it will be things like object.name and object.length. It could be complicated like datetime formatting. All expressions would be allowed by Ruby. When I get a string from the Document I will pass in the object(s) as a named hash probably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use or write your own templating engine. And by templating engine, I mean something as simple as:

```
values = {"foo" => "bar"}
"turn this {{foo}} into bar".gsub(/\{\{.+?\}\}/) do |x|
  values[x[2..-3]]
end

# => "turn this bar into bar"
```

You might also like liquid or mustache for this purpose. You can reject out of hand any solutions involving eval: they aren't safe with untrusted strings.

As far as storing the configuration values, mongo seems fine.

Comment: Excellent, that works for me, for now at least. One edit: you should remove the bracket on the 'values[x[2..-3]]' line, I think. I'll look at Liquid and Mustache if this isn't enough...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently facets allows you to do this, using `String.interpolate`. I came across it while watching [this video](http://confreaks.net/videos/479-larubyconf2011-active-support-3-it-s-finally-getting-interesting) this morning.